# Process raw data in PL/SQL without creating table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Experts,

I've to process the raw data received in the email.  This is one time request so I'm trying to figure easy and effective way to handle it without creating tables.

The raw data has 3 columns and may go up to 100 records.  Please see the raw data sample below:

[image]

I have created a stored procedure that accepts parameters: `participant_id, category_nmbr, group_id` and creates necessary transactions.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a wrapper program (anonymous PL/SQL block) that reads each row from the raw data and calls the stored procedure with said parameters.

I did explore composite datatypes, however, would like to keep the implementation as simple as possible without creating tables and type objects (if possible)

Appreciate help!

TIA

Comment: Is this a one-time load or a recurring thing?

Comment: If this is a one-time script and we're talking less than 100 rows, simply pop it into Excel and use Excel string concatenation to create a procedure call per row in a new column. Then copy the procedure call column and put into a script file and run that. 3 minutes tops.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load data into a table, then you have an option to create an **external table** which is a *pointer* to file stored in a filesystem directory, and which is accessible via Oracle directory object.

As you can't create it yourself (as an ordinary user), you'll have to talk to DBA to prepare that for you (create directory, grant privileges).

Then you'd create an external table and process it with procedure you've already written. A wrapper procedure (or anonymous PL/SQL block) is simple - just loop through all rows, e.g.

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select participant_id, category_nmbr, group_id
                from the_external_table)
  loop
    your_procedure (cur_r.participant_id, cur_r.category_nmbr, cur_r.group_id);
  end loop;
end;
```

---

If you'd rather load data into a table, you could use **SQL Loader** utility which doesn't require DBA action as file can reside on your own PC. You'd create target table, control file (which instructs the utility how to load data), perform loading operation and - once data is ready - use PL/SQL block I previously posted.

---

Yet another option is to read file contents with `UTL_FILE` built-in package, but it - again - requires directory object and is probably more complex than previous options.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot.  Since the one-time script will be deployed in different environments, I prefer not to create a directory since it involves approvals.  SQL Loader requires a target table to be created, also I've to create a separate set of deployment instructions which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.  I had to convert each column data into CSV then for each column then use the following query to get the data

```
WITH t_prctpnt_id
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM ptcpt_row_id,
                TO_CHAR (TO_NUMBER (db_id.COLUMN_VALUE)) participant_id
           FROM XMLTABLE ('101, 102, 203,204') db_id),
     t_ctgry_id
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM ctgry_row_id,
                TO_CHAR (TO_NUMBER (ctgry_id.COLUMN_VALUE)) category_nmbr
           FROM XMLTABLE ('1000, 1000, 2000, 2000') ctgry_id),
     t_grp_id
     AS (    SELECT DISTINCT ROWNUM grp_row_id,
                             TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (GRP_ID,
                                                  '[^,]+',
                                                  1,
                                                  LEVEL))
                                GROUP_ID
               FROM (SELECT ROWNUM, GRP_ID
                       FROM (SELECT 'AB, CD, EF, GH' GRP_ID FROM DUAL)) t
         CONNECT BY INSTR (GRP_ID,
                           ',',
                           1,
                           LEVEL - 1) > 0
           ORDER BY ROWNUM)
SELECT participant_id, category_nmbr, group_id
  FROM t_prctpnt_id d, t_ctgry_id P, t_grp_id g
 WHERE d.ptcpt_row_id = p.ctgry_row_id AND p.ctgry_row_id = g.grp_row_id
```